# Нужна помощь ошибка в коде

Tags: python

Ошибка типа:> не поддерживается между экземплярами str и int

Задача состоит в том, чтобы средний календарный год лучше соответствовал солнечному, в юлианском, потом и григорианском календаре в високосный год, в котором в феврале добавили еще одни, 29-е сутки.

В григорианском календаре (у нас все в живых) год является високосным в двух случаях: либо кратно 4, но не кратко 100, либо кратко 400. Напишите программу, которая принимает номер года и печатает "Високосный" или " Не високосный ".

```py
#Задача на Високосность
print('Здравствуйте,если хотите узнать какой год <Високоный или невисокосный>'
      'напишите год')
    year = input()
    if year  >4:
        if year <100:
            if year >400:
                print('Високосный')
    else:
        print('Не високосный')
```

Comment: А в чём заключается ваш вопрос? Устраните ошибку и вроде всё.

Comment: `input` возвращает строку, преобразуйте её в `int` перед сравнением с числом

Comment: `year = input()` заменить на: `year = int(input())`

Comment: Совершенно неправильный алгоритм. На 2020 год ничего не выдаст, хотя год високосный. Не говоря уже о том, что год не может быть одновременно меньше 100 и больше 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вместо

   ```
   year = input()
   ```

   примените

   ```
   year = int(input())
   ```

   чтобы вы строку (например `"2016"`) изменили на целое число (`2016`).
2. Вместо вашего неправильного кода для алгоритма по вычислении *високосный / невисокосный* можете использовать например

   ```
   if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
       print('Високосный')
   else:
       print('Не високосный')
   ```

   потому что вы хотите тест на *делимость*, а не на *больший / меньший.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понимаю, что очень лёгкий вопрос просто только начал изучать питон

Comment: Не стоит — мы все однажды начинали.